# Rails URL helpers and `delegated_type`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Let's say I have setup like the [`delegated_type`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html) docs:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :creator
  delegated_type :entryable, types: %w[ Message Comment ]
end

module Entryable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :entry, as: :entryable, touch: true
  end
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  include Entryable
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  include Entryable
end
```

And then I have `resources :messages` setup in my routes.

How do I use Rails url helpers with these, for example:

```
form_with model: Entry.new(entryable: Message.new)
```

So that it essentially resolves to `messages_path`

I've looked at both [`direct`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#direct-routes) and [`resolve`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-resolve) but am not sure if either of them are right as I can't get it to work with either.

---

*Edit:*

So I have part of it working, if I were to do:

```
resolve('Entry') { |e| [e.entryable_type.demodulize.downcase.to_sym] }
```

Then `url_for(@entry)` uses `message_path`.

But if I have messages nested like so:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :messages
end
```

Then `url_for(@account, @entry)` gives me this error:

```
undefined method `account_entry_path'
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this:

```rb
direct :entry do |entry|
  route_for(entry.entryable.model_name.singular_route_key, entry)
end

direct :account_entry do |account, entry|
  [account, entry.entryable]
end
```

---

```bash
undefined method `account_entry_path'
```

It's a method, you can define it, it's what `direct` does (except that it's defined in Rails.application.routes.url_helpers):

```rb
<%
  def account_entry_path(account, entry, opts = {})
    "/accounts/#{account.to_param}/entries/#{entry.to_param}"
  end
%>
<%= url_for [Account.first, Entry.first] %> #=> /accounts/1/entries/1
```

`resolve` doesn't work for nested  routes.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I needed. My models are namespaced (so Foo::Entry) so in `foo.rb` I just had to add `def self.use_relative_model_naming? = true` to get them working with this method. Thanks!